# Two dimensions jquery sortable retrieves a bug in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two dimensions sorting bug in IE8 and below.

IE just doesn't know to handle this thing.

[image: Image demonstrating the problem.]

As you can see, there are two levels of sorting items. Two dimensions.
In all of the browsers this thing works perfect. Only IE get crazy.

**My code**

```
 $("#experienciasProfissionais").sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    cursor: 'n-resize',
    handle: '.drag',
    axis: 'y',
    revert: true,
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.css('height', ui.item.css('height'));
    },
    tolerance: 'intersect'
});
$("#experienciasProfissionais > li > ul").sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    cursor: 'n-resize',
    axis: 'y',
    revert: true,
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.css('height', ui.item.css('height'));
    },
    tolerance: 'intersect'
});
```

The moment I let the first JQ object to run, everything gets messed up. He accept only one level of sorting. 2 are totally forbidden.

In FF & Chrome everything is just fine. Only IE gives the creeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem, but your code got me thinking. I believe the bug occurs because the item you are clicking is in both lists, and thus ambiguous. So, IE incorrectly decides to move what you are clicking, as well as any parents that are also sortable. The solution I found was to add a 'handle' definition to the shallow list (e.g. "#experienciasProfissionais > li > ul"). This eliminates the ambiguity so that the thing being dragged can only refer to one sortable list.

Comment: Hey Doug and sorry for the delay in responding to you.
I did played with Handles in this project & found Zitz :)
At the end I solved the issue the way BaseCampHq do - Sorting the upper level is done using a different place and not using Drag.
There's a link at the top of the module that invite users to sort the first dimension, and then they get redirected to a dedicated page for this matter, with all the items in a short and nice list. This solves a usability issue as well, when lots of content appear in the page, and the scroll becomes very very tall.

Answer (score 0):

```
newLi.find('ul.selectedFieldPlaceholder').sortable().bind('mousedown', function(oEvent, ui){
   oEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

I have a ul > li that is sortable and those li's also have ul's with sortable li's,
anyways all you have to do is call stopPropagation() on the 2nd level/nested ul and IE won't propagate your drag to the top level.